# Fixed or Absolute Position inside of a Bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I would like to have the right column remain absolute positioned as the user scrolls the left column. I've attempted to mimic every 'solution' I've found on stackoverflow and google, but the majority are old and none did the trick.

Here's my markup:

```
   <div className="wrapper wrapper-content animated">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
              { this.props.showController ? <ModelChartController handleChange={ this.handleChange } handleSavedUntilRetirementChange={ this.handleSavedUntilRetirementChange } handleSavedAfterRetirementChange={ this.handleSavedAfterRetirementChange }
                                              {...this.state} /> : null }
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
              <div className="absolute-wrapper">
                <div className="maintainPosition">
                  <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' aspect={ 21.0 / 9.0 }>
                    <LineChart data={ this.state.data } margin={ { top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 } }>
                      <XAxis dataKey="Age" />
                      <YAxis dataKey="Total" />
                      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                      <Tooltip/>
                      <Legend />
                      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Non-Retirement" stroke="#8884d8" />
                      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Retirement" stroke="#82aeca" />
                      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Total" stroke="#82ca9d" activeDot={ { r: 8 } } />
                    </LineChart>
                  </ResponsiveContainer>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.absolute-wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .maintainPosition {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? It's neither raw HTML or raw Bootstrap. Is this `ReactJS`?

Comment: Yes, it's a React component.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the .absolute-wrapper and .maintainPosition divs just for positioning (not sure if you need them for other styles).

The 2 columns are "col-lg-4 col-xl-4" (left column) and "col-lg-8 col-xl-8" (right column) and it would be proper to operate CSS on these divs.

You need to either append another class name, or assign an Id to these divs like so:

**Append Class Name:**

```
<div className="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 leftColumn">
...
</div>

<div className="col-lg-8 col-xl-8 rightColumn">
...
</div>
```

**CSS for Classes:**

```
.leftColumn {}
.rightColumn {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

**Add Id:**

```
<div className="col-lg-4 col-xl-4" id="leftColumn">
...
</div>

<div className="col-lg-8 col-xl-8" id="rightColumn">
...
</div>
```

**CSS for Ids:**

```
#leftColumn {}
#rightColumn {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

If that is not solving what you are looking for, try using `position: fixed;` (relative to the viewport) instead of `position: absolute;` (relative to the parent). This explains things in great detail: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/